# Using Sql 'In' Operator within .NET 2.0 DataTable Filter expression

Tags: .net-2.0, datatable

Does the .NET 2.0 Framework DataTable filterexperssion property support the SQL "IN" operator?  If you have a solution to this please provide example code.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The RowFilter property of a DataView doesn't support SQL in any way. Is this what you were referring to?